# UITableView undeclared type Cell?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a nearly working code, but Xcode complains about one line. As there is some other code in my project, I don't think it does matter.

I have this piece of code:

```
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! SpecialCell
    let maindata = values[indexPath.row]
    cell.username.text = maindata["Username"] as? String
    cell.password.text = maindata["Password"] as? String
    cell.num.text = maindata["FavoriteNumber"] as? String
    cell.info.text = maindata["Info"] as? String
    return cell;
}
```

I get the following error: "Use of undeclared type 'SpecialCell'".
Unfortunately, I have no idea how to deal with the SpecialCell. I think it is only is little thing i forgot. I googled more than one hour but I don't get it down.
If I change something in the mentioned line, all my cell.username.... statements are getting red.

All I've done is create a new Table View and linked it to my code. So I get this

```
@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
```

Do I have to change or set an identifier or something like this?
The idea of this project is, to parse data with JSON and write it to this table. The parsing code is this:

```
    func parseJson() {
    let url = NSURL(string: "http://an_url.com")
    let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: url!)
    values = try! NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers) as! NSArray
    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

But I think it doesn't matter on this special topic here.
It would be great if you have some tips for me.

Comment: Change it with UITableViewCell and let me know if it works

Comment: Thanks. I tried this before because the code completion recommended this. The effect is also that all my cell.username... statements are getting red.

Comment: This is probably because you have a custom cell, with a custom class but you have not given it a proper name in the XCode IDE: select your cell in your storyboard, open the Attributes Inspector and set the Identifier (remove "cell" and put SpecialCell)

Answer (score 0):

You can declare a custom cell like this

```
self.tableView.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "SpecialCell")
```

Or

```
self.tableView.registerClass(SpecialCell.classForCoder(), forCellReuseIdentifier: "SpecialCell")
```

If it's a custom cell. Tell us more about this SpecialCell

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your tips.
As I get a bit further, I realized, as Andrew McKinley said, SpecialCell is the definition of a custom cell. The solution was to create a class SpecialCell and define the cell in it.
Once, i have done this, I stuck on another point. But thats another topic.

Thanks again.